# what does projection $\pi$ mean?

Tags: projection

I am reading a paper where I encountered the following -

\begin{equation}
Z(x) = \pi_{[-c,c]^{n}} (\nabla F(x)-x)
\end{equation}

what does the first term mean? Its mentioned in the paper that $\pi_{[-c,c]^{n}} (q)$ is projection and it acts components wise on q - Which I cannot understand. Can someone elaborate on it?

Answer (score 0):

Let me try my shot at it. I believe x is a vector, e.g. 
`grad of F(x) = <Fx1, Fx2>`

`q = <Fx1, Fx2> - <x1, x2>`

`q = (Fx1 - x1)i + (Fx2 - x2)j`

q is a vector of component i & j.